# Failed @Inject object using RESTEasy, Weld and Wildfly

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, resteasy, wildfly, weld

I'm trying to make a REST webservice using RESTEasy and Weld for injection. When the package is deployed on wildfly I have no problem, but when trying test the service I get the error below.

I have no idea how to solve this.

Does anyone can help me?

```
21:54:17,066 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-19) UT005023: Exception handling request to /cdi-test/hello: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNotNull(Preconditions.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:766) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ParameterInjectionPointImpl.getValueToInject(ParameterInjectionPointImpl.java:76) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.getParameterValues(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:138) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:68) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:85) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:183) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.DestructibleBeanInstance.createAndInjectBeans(DestructibleBeanInstance.java:53) [hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.DestructibleBeanInstance.<init>(DestructibleBeanInstance.java:33) [hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorFactoryBean.createInstance(ValidatorFactoryBean.java:206) [hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorFactoryBean.createConstraintValidatorFactory(ValidatorFactoryBean.java:192) [hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorFactoryBean.create(ValidatorFactoryBean.java:119) [hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorFactoryBean.create(ValidatorFactoryBean.java:52) [hibernate-validator-cdi-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.proxies.ValidatorFactory$627848863$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getMessageInterpolator(Unknown Source) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.beanvalidation.LazyValidatorFactory.getMessageInterpolator(LazyValidatorFactory.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.GeneralValidatorImpl.getValidator(GeneralValidatorImpl.java:559) [resteasy-validator-provider-11-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.GeneralValidatorImpl.validate(GeneralValidatorImpl.java:69) [resteasy-validator-provider-11-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.JaxrsInjectionTarget.validate(JaxrsInjectionTarget.java:108) [resteasy-cdi-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.JaxrsInjectionTarget.inject(JaxrsInjectionTarget.java:69) [resteasy-cdi-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:150) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.test.service.HelloWorld$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getHelloWorldJSON(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    ... 31 more
```

My project files,

```
package com.test.service;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RESTConfig extends Application {

}
```

---

```
package com.test.service;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Path("/hello")
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorld {
    @Inject
    HelloService helloService;

    @GET
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public Response getHelloWorldJSON() {
        String res = helloService.createHelloMessage("World");
        return Response.ok(res).build();
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.test.service;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped
public class HelloService {

    String createHelloMessage(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

}
```

---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdi-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I've deleted the wildfly folder, unzip another one, then I follow the @Benjamin sugestion.

Comment: I put the packages as provided as Benjamin told, then I delete the old wildfly and unziped another one. In the new wildfly the solution works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not add weld and resteasy dependencies if you do not use specific weld or resteasy features. And if you do so, you should put those dependencies with the `provided` scope. Else it will be packaged in your WAR.

But looking at your code, you do not seem to use specific weld or resteasy features. What i recommend in this case, is just adding a single dependency for Java EE apis, and nothing else:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Wildfly will provide all implementations at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Java EE 7 has implicit bean archives by default. Your `HelloWorld` class does not have a scope annotation, so it's not regarded as a managed bean by CDI and injection into this class does not work.

Try adding `@ApplicationScoped`.

Comment: I do this change right now and still get the same error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using singletons to represent your endpoints.  Since you're instantiating them, you're bypassing injection.  You can either remove all methods from your `RESTConfig` class or make it return your class in `getClasses()`.  It's not necessary to specify them in an EE application as the container is intended to scan.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed all methods on RESTConfig and the error changed, I'm happy to see this change: 17:35:15,303 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-15) UT005023: Exception handling request to /cdi-test/hello: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null

Comment: Did you remove the scope added in the other answer? Make the resource as `@RequestScoped` and make sure you have a valid beans.xml.  Please also add the full stack trace to your original question.  What version of WildFly are you deploying to?

Comment: BTW, I noticed that your POM file has everything listed and probably in the compile scope.  Is Resteasy and Weld ending up in your war file?  Please try marking all of these as provided.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect the changes that i made, the beans.xml and the actual error message. I'm using wildfly-8.1.0.Final.

Comment: My pom.xml file is generating .jar not .war and the created jar has only the classes that I created. I will change that now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm packing my project using .war but now getting an [LinkageError](https://gist.github.com/raquel/44585c43d1cf78761f3f). I put [weld on wildfly](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/news/2014/04/15/weld-220-final/), changed weld scope to provided on pom.xml, but the error persist. Would be better if I create an separate questions for that?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. The solution was to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```